# Output array as comma separated with querySelector

Tags: javascript, npm

I am using querySelector from https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs and I want to output an array as as comma separated string.

I start with a URL search string and then parse it using `qs` I then tried the `qs` `stringify` method to return the formatted string.

```
const sUrl = 'a=1&b=1&c=1&c=2&c=3';
const oData = qs.parse(sUrl);
// oData returns: 
{
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: ['1', '2', '3']
}
const sData = qs.stringify(oData);
// sUrl returns: 'a=1&b=1&c%5B0%5D=1&c%5B1%5D=2&c%5B2%5D=3'
```

I want the output to be:
`a=1&b=1&c=1,2,3`

Comment: I found a second argument `arrayFormat: comma` but even that did not work. I expect because it's an array inside an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`qs` has an option to specify the array format, so to get the desired output, you can use:

```
qs.stringify(oData, { arrayFormat: 'comma', encode: false  })
```

`encode: false` is also used so the commas aren't URL encoded.

With an input of:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: ['1', '2', '3']
}
```

It will return:

```
a=1&b=1&c=1,2,3
```

Comment: That looks like a winner however if I do: `qs.stringify({a: 1, b: 1, c: ['1', '2', '3']}, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })` it returns `a=1&b=1&c%5B0%5D=1&c%5B1%5D=2&c%5B2%5D=3`

Comment: I've updated the answer with `{encode: false}` which seems to do the trick https://codesandbox.io/s/8nrj27q2z8

Comment: This is incredibly odd, now with `encoding: false` I get `a=1&b=1&c[0]=1&c[1]=2&c[2]=3`. Must be something in my environment because your code definitely works.

Comment: Looks like it's a version conflict Im on `6.6` and your codesandbox was on `6.7`. For some reason it's only working form `6.7`

Comment: That was a good find. Wonder if `6.6` was a regression, or if it was always like that, and they just decided to change the implementation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `qs` Is `arrayFormat` new to 6.7 or has it always been there?

Comment: I'm using `qs.stringify()` in a common place for every api call. Any way to prevent the comma to be encoded only for array parameter?